# "Add from web" link in "add picture" does not always show on mobile site

Tags: bug, mobile-web, editor, uploader

Normally the add picture dialog looks like this:

[image]

However,  if you follow the following specific sequence of events:

1. Click add picture in the post editor
2. Add a picture from the web (paste a link in, did not try this just with direct typing) and accept.
3. Click add picture in the post editor again.

You end up with:

[image]

The add from web link is replaced with cancel and add another image.

If you click cancel and add another image the web link comes back, so it's an easy workaround at least.

Note that this does not happen if you upload a picture from your phone in step 2. It only happens if you add from the web.

Android, Chrome